# come right out = come out right?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand "come right out" as "come out unchanged". Am I on the right track? Some nuance here seems to be elusive to me. Are "come right out" and "come out right" interchangeable?

> The New York Times tweeted just now:
> @nytimes
> “Anything that goes into a toilet would **come right out**.” Two former employees of New York Waterway filed a complaint in federal court alleging that the company dumped unfiltered wastewater into the Hudson River for years. The firm denies the allegations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence means that anything that goes into the toilet comes out, unfiltered or unsegregated, straight into the Hudson River (without any filtration processes involved on its way).

And no. They aren't interchangeable. **come right out** means, well what I explained above. **come out right** would suggest it is coming out in the right way, like something filtered.